# Spring boot application.properties reuse values

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

My question seems pretty simple but I could not find a way to implement it.

Consider the following case:

```
prop1 = value1
prop2 = value2
prop3 = value3

prop4 = value2     (Value same as prop2)
prop5 = value3     (Value same as prop3)
```

How to reuse value 2 and 3 (these are actually database specific properties) as I want the user to provide it only once and not repeat it.

Thanks.

Case 1:
I would elaborate my case as below:
I have two properties file - `application.properties` and `quartz.properties`.

application.properties:

```
prop1 = value1
prop2 = value2
prop3 = value3
```

quartz.properties

```
prop4 = value2     (Value same as prop2)
prop5 = value3     (Value same as prop3)
```

Please note: I cannot merge the contents of the two properties files and they are put separately for a reason.

In normal scenario I expected ${} to work but it doesn't work when the properties are in two different files I guess.

Case 2: [Simple scenario]
I tried using just one application.properties. But even then I am not able to reuse the property values in same property file.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xyz</name>
    <description>xyz</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Quartz dependencies start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Includes spring's support classes for quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz dependencies End -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Not sure that understood you properly. `prop4 = ${prop2}` maybe

Comment: Thanks John. I too thought this would work but it doesn't  :(

Comment: Then you could just use ${prop2} everywhere you need it, why to have this prop4 at all ?

Comment: The property names differ and they can't be named the same.

Comment: @sauveerpandey Could you please share your pom.xml and your project structure...

Comment: @VelNaga pom.xml code is as updated in my question. For project structure it is a simple spring boot application with application.properties under the usual `src/main/resources` directory. It is working properly ofcourse for all properties but as already put, I want to reuse some values.

Comment: As @john mentioned it should work...Could you please remove the Quartz dependency and check...also spring-context-support

Comment: Well interestingly, it works when Quartz dependencies have the actual values and quartz property names are used as placeholders.
This works
`org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user =username
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password

spring.datasource.username = ${org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user}
spring.datasource.password = ${org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password}`


Doesn't work
`spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password = password

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = ${spring.datasource.username}
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password =${spring.datasource.password}`

Comment: @sauveerpandey here precedence of properties matters.So Spring gives more precedence to quartz.properties then application.properties.If you want to use other way round, you can specify "spring.datasource.username" & "spring.datasource.password" in bootstrap.properties then you can refer those properties in quartz.properties.

Comment: @VelNaga I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use placeholder for it like this:

```
prop1 = value1
prop2 = value2
prop3 = value3

prop4 = ${prop2}     (Value same as prop2)
prop5 = ${prop3}     (Value same as prop3)
```

But note, that this should be in the `application.properties` so spring is aware of it. In case you want your custom file with properties it would make sense to config `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, as shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() throws IOException {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("custom.properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
}
```

Now you should be abe to:

```
@Value("${prop4}")
private String someValue;
```

And it should inject you the right value in your bean.

Comment: prop4 = ${value2} ?? or did you mean prop4 = ${prop2} ?

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake

Comment: I assume this is because Spring is not aware of your property file. To make it aware try to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as I just added to the answer.

Comment: For a quick test, I have put all properties in one single file "application.properties" (and ofcourse spring is aware of it). Even then prop4 = ${prop2}  doesn't work. I do not want add any config code and handle through properties file only.

Comment: That's strange. I tried to create a test project where I use placeholders just like this and it worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a yml file?